# Notify service that synchronizing complete

Tags: linux, asp.net-core

There is a web service that saves, among other things, files to file storage on linux os.
To access these files, it is periodically copied to another server using lsync.
Access is provided through nginx. Synchronization occurs every 10 seconds.

The problem is that client service could request files that just been saved and get 404.

Is it possible to notify the web service that synchronization has occurred and files are available for clients using the lsync functionality?
if not, then how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! This question could use some code. Can you also show what you have tried?

Comment: Web service just save files on file storage usinng SftpClient. On file server works lsynk like i wrote before. Service know nothing about lsynk and opposite.